# @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.hibernate.domain.Bee.honey references an unknown entity

Tags: java, hibernate

here is code

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "honey_seq", sequenceName = "honey_id_seq")
public class Honey implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "honey_seq")
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String taste;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "honey")
    private Set<Bee> bees = new HashSet<>();



@Entity
public class Bee implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "bee_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "bee_gen", sequenceName = "bee_id_seq")
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Honey honey;

    public Bee() {
    }
```

**Configuration**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sweet</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>


        <!-- Mappings -->

        <mapping class="com.hibernate.domain.Honey" />
        <mapping class="com.hibernate.domain.Bee" />
    </session-factory>
```

**Client.java**

```
public static Honey createHoney() {
        Honey forestHoney = new Honey();
        forestHoney.setName("forest Honey");
        forestHoney.setTaste("very sweet");
        Session sessoin = (Session) InitSessionFactory.getSessionFactoryInstance();
        Transaction transaction = sessoin.beginTransaction();
        sessoin.save(forestHoney);
        transaction.commit();
        sessoin.close();
        return forestHoney;
    }
```

**Stacktrace**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.hibernate.domain.Bee.honey references an unknown entity: com.hibernate.domain.Honey
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:97)
```

Not sure why I am getting this error, I am new to hibernate and this is my first program using hibernate.

After Searching various forms I'm not able to solve that error.

I'm not sure what went wrong and how to fix it,The one thing I doubt is that I'm missing some configuration and any hint is welcomed

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `@Entity` annotation to your `Honey` class so that Hibernate recognizes it as an entity.

Comment: That solved the error, but led to another error, won't you mind if I ask>

Comment: actually its `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl cannot be cast to org.hibernate.Session`

Comment: I don't mind, but you will have to provide information about how/where you're deploying this application, what libraries you're bundling, etc. So: create a new question and put all that information in.